# How to search for multiple terms in Wikidata API using 'srsearch' (e.g. from Python)?

Tags: python, wikidata, phabricator, wikidata-api

I am trying to search multiple terms on Wikidata and then parse the results locally using Python.

I am currently looping through a list of terms and running the following piece of code:

```
import requests 

term_list = ["term a", "term b"]

for search_term in term_list:
    base_url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php"
    payload = {
        "action": "query",
        "list": "search",
        "srsearch": search_term,
        "language": "en",
        "format": "json",
        "origin": "*",
    }
    res = requests.get(base_url, params=payload)
```

This takes a lot of time, as each iteration makes new requests.

Is there a way I could send a batch of terms simultaneously to the Wikidata API, thereby saving me time and saving resources to the API?

**edit**

By digging deeper in Phabricator, it seems that I can't actually do it (https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T194016). If anyone has more information on it, it would be very useful.

Comment: not possible via API. Even with a SPARQL query, internally a sequence of requests to the SERVICE would have been sent.

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks! If you move your comment to an answer, I'll gladly accept it.